# Can't read documentation in pow, launched form fv: Error: can't read "env(POW_HELPDIR)": no such variable

Tags: fits

I'm launching the `pow` tool from `fv` version 5.5, installed via apt on Ubuntu 20.04.
It is part of [HEASoft's FITS software suite](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/software.html).

I click on the menu Help/About and I get this error message:

```
Error: can't read "env(POW_HELPDIR)": no such variable
```

How can I get to the help files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After poking around a bit, I see that I can set this in Bash before running fv:

`export POW_HELPDIR=/usr/share/doc/ftools-pow`

which fixes it and lets me browse the help documentation.

*Update*: the FTOOLS Help Desk reports that this is apparently a packaging issue in Ubuntu, and is not a problem for the [versions they distribute directly](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/ftools/fv/fv_download.html).

*Update 2*: I just reported this bug to the packagers: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ftools-fv/+bug/1982671